# Showing 'run task' error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin

While running my project in emulator (AVD), it is showing 'Run task' error. But when I clean project without running in emulator, this issue is not seen. How can I solve it?

I've made a lot of internet research about this, but unfortunately nothing worked.

I made a 'login' slide for my dream project in android studio, initially it was perfect without any error. When I tried to run this in my emulator (AVD), an error was showing:

> **Build:build failed** >> **Run build** >> **Run tasks** >> **:app:mergerDebugResources** >> **Execute taskAction**.

(NB.: >> represents folder and sub-folder path of error)

When I clicked on 'Build:build failed'... it showed the following text in the near tab:

> **Android resource compilation failed
>   C:\Users\DELL\AndroidStudioProjects\XCity\app\src\main\res\layout-v4\activity_main.xml:110: error: not well-formed (invalid token)**.

Please note that I am a beginner, I don't have good idea about handling such issues earlier.

One more thing, I opened "hello world" project and run it, Emulator opened and shows 'process system is not responding'. I need to run my project in emulator.

Comment: where is your `activity_main.xml` and why even `layout-v4` ??

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there is an issue with your XML configuration. Just like this tool creates https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html

Comment: Edit token too*